# Instaling Photoshop CC 2015 at Debian 8.5 GNOME using PlayOnLinux failing after many attemps

Tags: playonlinux

First Attempt:

```
mv@Turing:~$ playonlinux
Looking for python... 2.7.9 - wxversion(s): 3.0-gtk2
selected
[main] Message: PlayOnLinux (4.2.10) is starting
[clean_tmp] Message: Cleaning temp directory
[Check_OpenGL] Message: 32bits direct rendering is enabled
[Check_OpenGL] Message: 64bits direct rendering is enabled
[POL_System_CheckFS] Message: Checking filesystem for /home/mv/.PlayOnLinux/
[main] Message: Filesystem is compatible
[install_plugins] Message: Verificando plug-in: Capture...
[install_plugins] Message: Verificando plug-in: ScreenCap...
[install_plugins] Message: Verificando plug-in: PlayOnLinux Vault...
[update_check] Message: List is up to date
[POL_Config_Write] Message: Config write: MANUAL_INSTALL_INCREMENT 19
[POL_SetupWindow_Init] Message: Creating new window for pid 5905
[POL_SetupWindow_menu] Message: menu answer: Editar ou atualizar um aplicativo existente
[POL_Wine_SelectPrefix] Message: Selecting prefix: PhotoshopCS6
[POL_System_SetArch] Message: POL_ARCH set to x86
[POL_SetupWindow_checkbox_list] Message: checkbox_list answer: Usar outra versão do Wine~Configurar o Wine
[POL_SetupWindow_menu] Message: menu answer: 1.9.18
[POL_System_SetArch] Message: POL_ARCH set to x86
[POLsing Library Code:_SetupWindow_menu_num] Message: menu_num answer: 1
[POL_System_SetArch] Message: POL_ARCH set to amd64
[POL_Wine] Message: Running wine-1.7.46-staging winecfg (Working directory : /home/mv/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/PhotoshopCS6)
[POL_Wine] Message: Notice: PlayOnLinux deliberately disables winemenubuilder. See http://www.playonlinux.com/fr/page-26-Winemenubuilder.html
fixme:winediag:start_process Wine Staging 1.7.46 is a testing version containing experimental patches.
fixme:winediag:start_process Please report bugs at http://bugs.wine-staging.com (instead of winehq.org).
fixme:ole:RemUnknown_QueryInterface No interface for iid {00000019-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}
fixme:ole:RemUnknown_QueryInterface No interface for iid {00000019-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}
fixme:msg:pack_message msg 14 (WM_ERASEBKGND) not supported yet
fixme:msg:pack_message msg 14 (WM_ERASEBKGND) not supported yet
[POL_Wine] Message: Wine return: 0
[main] Message: Autorun : Checking DATA...
[main] Message: Autorun: Found 0 media
[POL_SetupWindow_browse] Message: browser answer: /home/mv/Downloads/AdobePhotoshop17-mul_x64/Set-up.exe
[POL_System_CheckFS] Message: Checking filesystem for /home/mv/Downloads/AdobePhotoshop17-mul_x64/Set-up.exe
[POL_Wine] Message: Running wine-1.7.46-staging /home/mv/Downloads/AdobePhotoshop17-mul_x64/Set-up.exe (Working directory : /)
fixme:winediag:start_process Wine Staging 1.7.46 is a testing version containing experimental patches.
fixme:winediag:start_process Please report bugs at http://bugs.wine-staging.com (instead of winehq.org).
fixme:ole:RemUnknown_QueryInterface No interface for iid {00000019-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000800)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000800)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000800)
fixme:advapi:EventRegister {5eec90ab-c022-44b2-a5dd-fd716a222a15}, 0x401123, 0x58c0d0, 0x58c0e8
fixme:advapi:EventSetInformation 2, 0x57c820, 43
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000800)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000800)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000800)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000800)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000800)
fixme:ieframe:PersistStreamInit_InitNew (0x15d860)
fixme:ieframe:OleObject_Advise (0x15d860)->(0x158f14, 0x158f6c)
fixme:ieframe:ViewObject_SetAdvise (0x15d860)->(1 00000000 0x158f14)
fixme:ieframe:ViewObject_Draw (0x15d860)->(1 -1 (nil) (nil) (nil) 0xb0031 0x158f84 0x158f84 (nil) 00000000)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000800)
fixme:ieframe:WebBrowser_put_RegisterAsDropTarget (0x15d860)->(0)
fixme:ieframe:WebBrowser_put_RegisterAsBrowser (0x15d860)->(0)
fixme:ieframe:WBServiceProvider_QueryService (0x15d860)->({cb728b20-f786-11ce-92ad-00aa00a74cd0}, {cb728b20-f786-11ce-92ad-00aa00a74cd0} 0x32fba8)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000800)
fixme:ieframe:PersistStreamInit_InitNew (0x155830)
fixme:ieframe:OleObject_Advise (0x155830)->(0x1bcc9c, 0x1bccf4)
fixme:ieframe:ViewObject_SetAdvise (0x155830)->(1 00000000 0x1bcc9c)
fixme:ieframe:ViewObject_Draw (0x155830)->(1 -1 (nil) (nil) (nil) 0xb0031 0x1bcd0c 0x1bcd0c (nil) 00000000)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000800)
fixme:ieframe:WebBrowser_put_RegisterAsDropTarget (0x155830)->(0)
fixme:ieframe:WebBrowser_put_RegisterAsBrowser (0x155830)->(0)
fixme:ieframe:WBServiceProvider_QueryService (0x155830)->({cb728b20-f786-11ce-92ad-00aa00a74cd0}, {cb728b20-f786-11ce-92ad-00aa00a74cd0} 0x32fba8)
err:winediag:schan_imp_init Failed to load libgnutls, secure connections will not be available.
err:winediag:SECUR32_initNTLMSP ntlm_auth was not found or is outdated. Make sure that ntlm_auth >= 3.0.25 is in your path. Usually, you can find it in the winbind package of your distribution.
fixme:dwmapi:DwmIsCompositionEnabled 0x6cb0bfac
fixme:iphlpapi:NotifyIpInterfaceChange (family 0, callback 0x69e6d901, context 0x19d3d60, init_notify 0, handle 0x229e7d4): stub
fixme:iphlpapi:CancelMibChangeNotify2 (handle (nil)): stub
fixme:imm:ImmReleaseContext (0x10078, 0x1a9d60): stub
fixme:ole:RemUnknown_QueryInterface No interface for iid {00000019-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}
fixme:ntdll:NtLockFile I/O completion on lock not implemented yet
fixme:ieframe:BrowserService_GetTravelLog 0x1a57c0 0x32d6ec
fixme:ieframe:ClOleCommandTarget_Exec Unimplemented cmdid 84 of CGID_ShellDocView
fixme:ieframe:ClOleCommandTarget_QueryStatus (0x15d918)->((null) 1 0x32d6f0 (nil))
fixme:ieframe:ClOleCommandTarget_QueryStatus command_0: 27, 0x0
fixme:ieframe:ClOleCommandTarget_Exec Unimplemented cmdid 25
fixme:ieframe:ClOleCommandTarget_Exec Unimplemented cmdid 26
fixme:ieframe:ClOleCommandTarget_Exec Unimplemented cmdid 37 of CGID_ShellDocView
fixme:ieframe:ClOleCommandTarget_Exec Unimplemented cmdid 84 of CGID_ShellDocView
fixme:ieframe:ClientSite_GetContainer (0x15d918)->(0x32d6cc)
fixme:mshtml:nsChannel_GetContentDisposition (0x167098)->(0x32ce34)
fixme:mshtml:nsChannel_GetContentDispositionHeader (0x167098)->(0x32c654)
fixme:ieframe:ClientSite_GetContainer (0x15d918)->(0x32e76c)
fixme:ieframe:ClOleCommandTarget_Exec Unimplemented cmdid 25
fixme:ieframe:ClOleCommandTarget_Exec Unimplemented cmdid 26
fixme:ieframe:DocHostContainer_exec Exec failed
fixme:ieframe:DocHostUIHandler_GetDropTarget (0x15d918)
fixme:ieframe:DocHostContainer_exec Exec failed
fixme:ieframe:ClOleCommandTarget_Exec Unimplemented cmdid 28
fixme:dwmapi:DwmGetCompositionTimingInfo ((nil) 0x32f660)
fixme:advapi:RegisterTraceGuidsW (0x69cd0301, 0x4358920, {509962e0-406b-46f4-99ba-5a009f8d2225}, 3, 0x4b62410, (null), (null), 0x4358950): stub
fixme:advapi:RegisterTraceGuidsW   register trace class {a3da04e0-57d7-482a-a1c1-61da5f95bacb}
fixme:advapi:RegisterTraceGuidsW   register trace class {917b96b1-ecad-4dab-a760-8d49027748ae}
fixme:advapi:RegisterTraceGuidsW   register trace class {26d1e091-0ae7-4f49-a554-4214445c505c}
fixme:mountmgr:harddisk_ioctl Unsupported ioctl 2d1400 (device=2d access=0 func=500 method=0)
fixme:mountmgr:harddisk_ioctl Unsupported ioctl 2d1400 (device=2d access=0 func=500 method=0)
fixme:mountmgr:harddisk_ioctl Unsupported ioctl 2d1400 (device=2d access=0 func=500 method=0)
fixme:jscript:JScriptProperty_SetProperty Unimplemented property 70000001
fixme:jscript:JScriptProperty_SetProperty Unimplemented property 70000002
fixme:mshtml:ASServiceProvider_QueryService (0x16b750)->({75dd09cb-6c40-11d5-8543-00c04fa0fba3} {0000000c-0000-0000-c000-000000000046} 0x32d278)
fixme:mshtml:ASServiceProvider_QueryService (0x16b750)->({fc4801a1-2ba9-11cf-a229-00aa003d7352} {fc4801a1-2ba9-11cf-a229-00aa003d7352} 0x32d28c)
fixme:mshtml:ASServiceProvider_QueryService (0x16b750)->({75dd09cb-6c40-11d5-8543-00c04fa0fba3} {0000000c-0000-0000-c000-000000000046} 0x32d2a4)
fixme:ieframe:ClOleCommandTarget_Exec Unimplemented cmdid 69 of CGID_Explorer
fixme:ieframe:PropertyNotifySink_OnChanged unimplemented dispid 1005
fixme:ieframe:ClOleCommandTarget_Exec Unimplemented cmdid 69 of CGID_Explorer
fixme:mshtml:nsChannel_Open (0x5520690)->(0x328100)
fixme:ieframe:ClOleCommandTarget_Exec Unimplemented cmdid 26
fixme:ieframe:DocHostContainer_exec Exec failed
fixme:ieframe:ClOleCommandTarget_Exec Unimplemented cmdid 103 of CGID_ShellDocView
fixme:ieframe:ClOleCommandTarget_Exec Unimplemented cmdid 2315 of group {de4ba900-59ca-11cf-9592-444553540000}
fixme:ieframe:ClOleCommandTarget_Exec Unimplemented cmdid 35
fixme:mshtml:HTMLElement_put_ondragstart (0x52fdbb8)->(0x32dda0 {VT_DISPATCH: 0x5559260})
```

Comment: https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=32438

Comment: Couldn't "you can't, it's unsupported" be an Answer?

Comment: @JeffSchaller I've withdrawn my close vote. The link I provided shows that it **apparently _is supported_ after all**. I have no idea how I got _unsupported_. PS 2016 maybe?

Answer (score 0):

According to WineHQ [Photoshop CC 2015 on Linux is known to work](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=32438). However, the test scenario uses a considerably more recent version of Wine that you are using (1.9.18 vs 1.7.46).

In my own (limited) experience, having a sufficiently recent version of Wine is essential. So I would recommend you upgrade to the latest version and follow the [recommendations for this application](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=32438).